# Reusing Bitmap variable for Image.Save, GDI+ Error

Tags: .net, image

I have a series of bitmap images that I need to save using .NET (C#) but am running into the generic GDI+ error.

I am trying to reuse the same variable which may be my problem.

For example:

```
Bitmap pic = MethodThatReturnsBitmap();
pic.Save(MyPath);

pic = AnotherMethodThatReturnsBitmap();
pic.Save(AnotherPath);
```

Do I need to introduce unique variables and/or dispose between each `.Save()`?

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is from just this code, but it can't be the fact you use the same variable since it's just a pointer.

Comment: I would suggest adding a break-point or a small delay after the first save and see if it works (for testing only). It may be a disposing issue.

Comment: @Doggett - I left it a bit simplified on purpose, I am getting different results running similar code on different test machines, so the error is not always consistent. In other words, it works sometimes, but also throws the exception on `Save` occasionally. I'm inclined to think a delay/dispose (as AJ and JTA suggest) are the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDI+ is really finicky about resource management.  I have found that, when in doubt, always, always `.Dispose()` when you have finished a set of operations with a Bitmap.  So, the simple answer is, yes, I think you need to Dispose().  I would go even further and put both Bitmaps in `using` statements.

```
using(Bitmap pic = MethodThatReturnsBitmap())
{
    pic.Save(Path);
}
using(Bitmap pic = AnotherMethodThatReturnsBitmap())
{
    pic.Save(AnotherPath);
}
```

Comment: Seems unlikely to be the problem, if this was true you could never save an image without having to dispose it afterwards. Which would be rather strange, ofcourse if you're not going to do anything else with it anyhow it's always better to dispose or use using.

Comment: It turns out that an Image property of one of my objects was throwing the exception when I called `Save` on it; by instantiating a new bitmap from it, enclosed in a using statement, the problem has went away. Thanks for the suggestion.